# What is the new way of detecting the change in dimensions of a stream?

Tags: ios, delegates, frame, opentok, valuechangelistener

An old version of the *iOS **OpenTok** Framework* had the following *delegate* method to detect the *dimension* or *frame* changes of a subscriber stream.

```
- (void)stream:(OTStream*)stream didChangeVideoDimensions:(CGSize)dimensions;
```

The *new version* of the framework does not have a similar method.

What is the ***new way*** of detecting the dimension changes of a subscriber stream?

Or is there a way in *iOS* in which I can attach a *listener* to the dimensions of the video stream?

Comment: Please add a link to the OpenTok framework site.

Comment: https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/

Answer (score 2):

The `videoDimensions` property of an OTStream object is Key-Value Coding compliant, and therefore you can use [Key Value Observing to receive a notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) when the value changes.

Here is an example (didn't run this myself):

(Inside an OTSessionDelegate, OTSubscriberDelegate implementation)

```
- (void)session:(OTSession *)session streamCreated:(OTStream *)stream
{
    // Assuming there is only one subscriber and its a property of self
    self.subscriber = [[OTSubscriber alloc] initWithStream:stream delegate:self];
    OTError *subscribeError;
    [session subscribe:self.subscriber error:&subscribeError];
    // TODO: check error
    // TODO: Add self.subscriber.view to self.view
}

- (void)session:(OTSession *)session streamDestroyed:(OTStream *)stream
{
    if ([stream.streamId isEqualToString:self.subscriber.stream.streamId]) {
        OTError *unsubscribeError;
        [session unsubscribe:self.subscriber error:unsubscribeError];
        // TODO: check error
        // Unregister for updates to video dimensions
        [self.subscriber.stream removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoDimensions"];
        // TODO: remove self.subscriber.view from self.view
    }
}

- (void)subscriberVideoDataReceived:(OTSubscriber *)subscriber
{
    // Read initial video dimensions
    CGSize videoDimensions = subscriber.stream.videoDimensions;
    // Register for updates to video dimensions
    [subscriber.stream addObserver:self
                        forKeyPath:@"videoDimensions"
                           options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                                      NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                           context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"videoDimensions"]) {
        // Read new value for video dimensions
        CGSize newVideoDimensions = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    }
}
```